# Angular reactive form pass wrong date

Tags: javascript, angular, date, primeng

I am using PrimeNg calendar module for picking up a date. I have the following code :

```
 <p-calendar formControlName="valid_till" [dateFormat]="'mm/dd/yy'"></p-calendar>
```

Now when I select a date for eg: `31st July 2020`, in the component, if I log the value I am getting the following :

```
Fri Jul 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But when I pass this value to the server as follows :

```
this.myService
    .save(this.myForm.value, this.editId);
```

It is passing the date as `valid_till: "2020-07-30T18:30:00.000Z"` and this value is saved in the database as `2020-07-30 23:59:59`. But I have to save it as `2020-07-31 23:59:59`. why it is happening like this and how can I save the exact date that I am selected ?

I have tried to add the offset as seen in another post like

```
newDate =  new Date(date_valid_till.getTime() +date_valid_till.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

But this has again given me `Thu Jul 30 2020 18:29:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`, still not the date I would like to have. I only need `Thu Jul 31` which I have selected in the date picker.

PS : I am using MySQL database and the column is of type DateTime.

Comment: here is the issue of timezone.

Comment: How this can be fixed ? I have tried to add the offset like `newDate =  new Date(date_valid_till.getTime() + date_valid_till.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);` but it has given me `Thu Jul 30 2020 18:29:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and it is still one day off

Comment: use the moment to set the timezone

Comment: But as the form field is datepicker, if i set using moment, it is showing some error when I use pathvalue. It should be a date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **dataType** as **string**.

```
<p-calendar formControlName="valid_till" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
```

I have created the **stackblitz**, its working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5ifcn

Comment: When I use it , I am getting `core.js:6228 ERROR Unexpected literal at position 2`

Comment: Yes it is. You are a lifesaver. Actually I was using moment and all even after changing the `dataType`. thanks a lot !!